# I am not able to install wine

Tags: 12.10, wine

I can't install wine in Ubuntu 12.10. The report is:

```
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas: (The following packages have unmet dependencies)

wine1.4: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) pero 1.16.7ubuntu6 no está 
 instalado  
          Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) pero 2.15-0ubuntu20 no está instalado  
          Depends: wine1.4-amd64 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1) pero 1.4.1-0ubuntu1 no está instalado  
          Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1) pero no va a ser instalado
```

I would like that you help me in this problem. Thanks for everything.

Comment: What is the command you tried? `sudo apt-get install wine` or any thing with a specific version number? or a downloaded .deb?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you tried to install Wine from a .deb package, but it's not recommended as you can easily install it using the Ubuntu repository.

To install Wine from the Ubuntu repository use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```